# Grails ACL independent controller action

Tags: grails

I have already implemented Grails acl in one of my project. now trying to reuse it in another project. To do this, i have done all necessary configuration for the acl to be implemented. After that i have created a controller named 'stock' and trying to call it's 'index' action to view index page of stock.

So, i created a link in my desired page in both the following ways

```
<a href="${createLink(uri: '/Stock')}">stock</a>
<g:link controller="Stock" action="index">stock</g:link>
```

But the problem is when the link is clicked always it goes to /login/auth instead of stock/index action although no grails acl annotation is used in the 'stock' controller. so stock controller is independent of authentication.

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are using spring-security plugin with the url's access ACL defined in your Config.groovy:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
'/':                              ['permitAll'],
'/index':                         ['permitAll'],
'/index.gsp':                     ['permitAll'],
'/**/js/**':                      ['permitAll'],
'/**/css/**':                     ['permitAll'],
'/**/images/**':                  ['permitAll'],
'/**/favicon.ico':                ['permitAll']]
```

If a url is not defined here than it need authentication. Adding 
     `'/stock/**':['permitAll']`
in that map is the solution.

Comment: thanks for your answer. but in case of spring-security-core:1.2.7.3, permit all feature was not used. suppose that this feature is needed in case of spring-security-core:2.0-RC2.I'll check this later and let you know whether it worked or not :)

Comment: Sorry for mistake, however in spring-security-core:1.2.7.3 in 'grails.plugins.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap' (in Config.groovy) you can use  '/stock/**':['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'].